# Customer who bought from you in the past, and buys again because they like the product

Tags: business-japanese, word-requests

I am looking for a shorter word to convey the fact that a customer buys again:

> 去年のお客さんが今年も買ってくれたので、価値があるかと思います

I want to insist on the fact that a customer buying again means that they like the product and think the price is fair.

It is only the second time they buy, though, so "regular" is probably a bit too strong.

I haven't found anything similar on ALC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 常連
- 常連客
- 常連のお客様
- お得意様
- リピーター
- リピート客

> こちらの化粧品は、常連のお客様もたくさんいらっしゃいます。
>
> リピーターを増やすための販売戦略を考える